# SqlBulkcopy .net 4.0 cannot access destination table

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have written a program that in .net that should copy tables data from one server to another. However I am getting an error:

> cannot access destination table "mytable"

Despite googling and looking everywhere I cannot find a solution to the error I am getting

Some posts mentions permissions and I have done the following:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT TO bulkadmin
```

but still no success.

Am I missing the obvious?

Help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I bulk copy 3 databases with 1000 tables to 01 "target" database.
I have simplified the code that I use and also tested with no luck.The intention is todo in Parallel ,but I want to get it working with a simple table first

```
private void TestBulkCopy(string sourceServer, string sourceDatabase, List<string> sourceTables)
    {
            string connectionStringSource = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
            string connectionStringTarget = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;

            string sqlGetDataFromSource = string.Format("SELECT * FROM  {0}", "testTable");

            using (var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringSource))
            {
                sourceConnection.Open();
                using (var cmdSource = new SqlCommand(sqlGetDataFromSource, sourceConnection))
                using (SqlDataReader readerSource = cmdSource.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (var sqlTargetConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringTarget))
                    {
                        sqlTargetConnection.Open();

                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlTargetConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "testTable";
                            bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += OnSqlRowsCopied;
                            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 2600;
                            bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 50;
                            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(readerSource);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not much to go on ..... can you show us some code? What does your table look like (structure)? What does your C# code using the `SqlBulkCopy` look like?

Comment: Hi marc_s, I have edited the question and I put the c# code I use .regarding the tables i have 1000 tables so not sure the structure helps, since I will not be able to modify them.It's a straight copy of data from one table to another with exactly the same structure.Thanks for your time

Comment: And the **table structure** ???

Answer (score 1):

Write the Schema before the table Name

Change

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "testTable";
```

to

```
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.testTable";
```

Comment: Thanks dude. It's helped me lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your destination table have defined field with auto-number identify. So, `SqlBulkCopy` can not copy values into that column. You must OFF that to-number identify column on destination table using this code :

```
BEGIN
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT [building] ON;

   INSERT INTO [Table2](.....)  
   VALUES(@id, @id_project,....)

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT [building] OFF;
END
```

or edit definition of destination table and remove auto-number identify on that column.

Answer (score 0):

The table name in **WriteToServer** method of **SqlBulkCopy** must be surrounded with **[ ]** signs.